# How do you merge small gaps into the larger surrounding polygon?

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I have a layer which has small rectangular gaps, I need to merge the gaps into the larger polygon that surrounds it, has anyone got any idea of how to do this, I know i can fill in the gaps with a new feature then go to Editor> Merge, but i have hundreds of these. If theres a way of doing this via vba or python, it would be great.

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3.1 (ArcEditor)

Heres what it looks like
[image: gaps is layer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks both, but I've found some vba code that did exactly what i wanted and was written by Kirk Kuykendall (so thanks Kirk).

Code is below

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    ' loop through each selected feature
    ' and merge it with the adjacent feature
    ' that is largest.

    Dim pEditor As IEditor
    Set pEditor = _
      Application.FindExtensionByName("ESRI Object Editor")

    If pEditor.EditState <> esriStateEditing Then
        MsgBox "start editing first"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pEL As IEditLayers
    Set pEL = pEditor
    If pEL.CurrentLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType _
       <> esriGeometryPolygon Then
        MsgBox "target layer not polygons"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pFSel As IFeatureSelection
    Set pFSel = pEL.CurrentLayer
    If pFSel.SelectionSet.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "nothing selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pFCur As IFeatureCursor
    pFSel.SelectionSet.Search Nothing, False, pFCur

    pEditor.StartOperation
    Dim pFeat As IFeature
    Set pFeat = pFCur.NextFeature
    Do Until pFeat Is Nothing
        Dim pLargestAdj As IFeature
        Set pLargestAdj = GetLargestAdjacent(pFeat)
        If Not pLargestAdj Is Nothing Then
            Dim pTopoOp As ITopologicalOperator
            Set pTopoOp = pLargestAdj.ShapeCopy
            Set pLargestAdj.Shape = pTopoOp.Union(pFeat.ShapeCopy)
            pLargestAdj.Store
            pFeat.Delete
        Else
            Debug.Print "nothing adjacent to: " & pFeat.OID
        End If
        Set pFeat = pFCur.NextFeature
    Loop
    pEditor.StopOperation "merge"
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh
End Sub

Function GetLargestAdjacent(pFeat As IFeature) As IFeature
    Dim pSF As ISpatialFilter
    Set pSF = New SpatialFilter
    Set pSF.Geometry = pFeat.Shape
    pSF.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelIntersects

    Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
    Set pFC = pFeat.Class
    Dim pFCur As IFeatureCursor
    Set pFCur = pFC.Search(pSF, False)

    Dim pFeat2 As IFeature, pLargestFeat As IFeature
    Dim dMaxArea As Double
    Set pFeat2 = pFCur.NextFeature
    Do Until pFeat2 Is Nothing
        If pFeat2.OID <> pFeat.OID Then
            If pLargestFeat Is Nothing Then
                Set pLargestFeat = pFeat2
                dMaxArea = GetArea(pFeat2.Shape)
            Else
                If GetArea(pFeat2.Shape) > dMaxArea Then
                    Set pLargestFeat = pFeat2
                    dMaxArea = GetArea(pFeat2.Shape)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Set pFeat2 = pFCur.NextFeature
    Loop
    Set GetLargestAdjacent = pLargestFeat

End Function

Function GetArea(pArea As IArea) As Double
    GetArea = pArea.Area
End Function
```

Forum link is here http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=87064#238942

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a bunch of geoprocessing tools.

1. Create a new large polygon layer that encompasses all features with holes
2. Run the [Symmetrical Difference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Symmetrical_Difference/00080000000r000000/) tool
3. Run the [Multipart To Singlepart](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Multipart_To_Singlepart/00170000003r000000/) tool
4. Delete the one very large feature from Multipart To Singlepart result layer
5. Run [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/), Target feature = result of Multipart To Singlepart layer
6. Run [Merge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Merge/001700000055000000/) Tool
7. Run [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dissolve/00170000005n000000/) Tool, Dissolve Field option check the common ID field, and check the Unsplit lines check box

Once tested you could create a model within model builder and configure this process into a script.  Sorry, links provided are for ArcGIS 10, same methodology though.

Comment: The symmetrical Difference tool is ArcInfo only, I've only got ArcEditor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a much easier answer to this one which I uncovered via a [Discussion Forum posting](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=2370&t=261879#943047) a few years ago.  That is to  run the [Union tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1342&pid=1336&topicname=Union_%28Analysis%29) on the feature class in question (so it is the only feature class in the list) and uncheck the Gaps Allowed checkbox.

You will then need to [Eliminate](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1766&pid=1762&topicname=Eliminate_%28Data_Management%29) these small polygons which is easy using the tool of the same name in ArcInfo but should also be achievable with an ArcView or ArcEditor license using an [ArcScript](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14672).